# Adding days to GNU date command with time stamp

Tags: bash

When I run this command I get what you'd expect:

```
date -d "2018-06-07 + 1 days"
Fri Jun  8 00:00:00 CEST 2018
```

1 day is added to the day provided (using midnight as starting point).

However when I try to work in a time (17:00:00), two things happen.

```
date -d "2018-06-07 17:00:00 + 28 days"
```

1. Up to 25 days, the output is wrong: wrong dates/wrong time (I have run this in a loop).
2. Above 25 days, it starts spitting out "date: invalid date ‘2018-06-07 17:00:00 +25 days’"

The manpage says about -d /--date that is pretty much free format. But I'm starting to think the plus sign is incorrectly interpreted (maybe as a timezone offset?) when you use the time (hours:minutes:seconds)?

So how can I add days FROM a timestamped date?

Comment: You should read "Date input formats" in the `info date` pages. Put the date addition next to the date: `date -d "2018-06-07 + 28 days 17:00:00"`

Comment: Inian's answer works, but this is even better (one-liner). Thanks!

Comment: You can work in seconds since epoch, but all numeric additions/subtractions must be done and then preceded by an `'@'`, e.g. to add 30 days, `date -d "@$(($(date "+%s") + 30*24*3600))"`, result: `Sat Jul  7 10:22:31 CDT 2018`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For increment on the days with timestamp to work, the timestamp needs to be in the standard format returned by default by the `date` command. So sanitize the date to a format in which it *accepts* minute arithmetic and do the processing.

```
date -d "2018-06-07 17:00:00"
Thu, Jun 07, 2018  5:00:00 PM
```

Now put it in a variable, e.g. putting your string in the example below

```
dateStr=$(date -d "2018-06-07 17:00:00")
date -d "$dateStr + 28 days"
```

returns

```
Thu, Jul 05, 2018  5:00:00 PM
```

The example uses timezones from IST.